# Can you password protect a New google sites page or use page-level permissions

Tags: html, passwords, google-workspace, google-sites-2016

Anyone have ideas how to password protect a New Google-sites **page** or the entire site? No page-level permissions for New sites yet. Trying to share a couple pages with public and one with specific users.

Make a single account within your Google Workspace and share the site internally. You can't use your custom domain, only sites.google.com/xxx. Doesn't seem to work, see below...

Or other ideas, besides going to wix, squarespace, et al, which **ALL** allow password protected pages/ page level permissions. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This might be a workaround, except it doesn't work either:
Share a website created with New Google Sites with a specific google account who can be a "Published Viewer".

Comment: I created a website in New Google Sites using a personal account.
I want a single Workspace account to be able to view the site.
I have shared the website with the account. They get a permission error after signing in saying no access to app. (other personal Google accounts can view this site fine).

I have turned *ON* Sites for the Workspace account but have turned OFF other apps. Anyone know what other settings are required for accounts to be able to view google sites? Or have a better workaround to page level permissions?